# RegionPlot: building a list of inequalities

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation, hold

I have a function like this:

```
Myfunction[x_,y_]:={Max[1, Min[x, 2]], Max[1, Min[y, 2]]}
```

and I need to do a `RegionPlot` like this:

```
RegionPlot[{Myfunction[x, y] == {1, 1}, Myfunction[x, y]  == {1, 2}, 
  Myfunction[x, y] == {2, 1}, Myfunction[x, y]== {2, 2}}, 
 {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

I would like to be able to define a list of conditions and  then make some kind of thread of the function with the list and plug it in the `RegionPlot` argument:

```
z = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};
```

Something like this (it doesn't work):

```
eq = Table["Myfunction[x,y]", {i, Length[z]}];
rplot = Thread[eq == z];

RegionPlot[rplot, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

**Edit**
The actual function I'm using is this one (it's a little bulky):

```
    Clear["Global`*"]
    ClearAll[Subscript]
    rho = 1; r = 0.8;
    m = 3; n = 2 ;

A = Table[1/n, {i, n}];
V = Table[1/m*i, {i, m}];
G = Table[1/m, {i, m}];

W1[i_, j_, c1_] :=rho*A[[1]]/r*(V[[i]] -rho/r*(Sum[G[[z]]*A[[1]]*(V[[z]] - V[[i]]), {z, i + 1, j}] + Sum[G[[k]]*(V[[k]] - (A[[1]]*V[[i]] + A[[2]]*V[[j]])), {k,j + 1, m}]) - c1)*(1 - Sum[G[[s]], {s, 1, i - 1}]);
W2[i_, j_, c2_] :=rho*A[[2]]/r*(V[[i]]-rho/r*(Sum[G[[z]]*A[[2]]*(V[[z]] - V[[i]]), {z, i + 1, j}] +Sum[G[[k]]*(V[[k]] - (A[[2]]*V[[i]] + A[[1]]*V[[j]])), {k,j + 1, m}]) - c2)*(1 - Sum[G[[s]], {s, 1, i - 1}]);


Nhfunction[c1_, c2_] :=
      Module[{},
game = Table[0, {i, m}, {j, m}, {z, n}];
Do[game[[i, j, 1]] = W1[i, j, c1]; 
game[[i, j, 2]] = W2[j, i, c2], {i, m}, {j, m}];
nash = Table[0, {i, m}, {j, n}];
Do[nash[[i,1]] = {Position [game[[All, i, 1]], Max[game[[All, i, 1]]]],i} //Flatten, {i, m}];
Do[nash[[i,2]] = {i,Position [game[[i, All, 2]], Max[game[[i, All, 2]]]]} //Flatten, {i, m}];
Nasheq = Select[nash[[All, 1]], MemberQ[nash[[All, 2]], #] &];
Return[Nasheq // Flatten]];
```

[image]

--Testing solution--

```
minnh = Nhfunction[0, 0][[1]];
maxnh = Nhfunction[1, 1][[1]];
znh = Tuples[Table[i, {i, minnh, maxnh}], 2]
Evaluate@Table[Nhfunction[0.2, 0.2] == i, {i, znh}]
RegionPlot[Evaluate@Table[Nhfunction[x, y] == i, {i, znh}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
RegionPlot[{Nhfunction[x, y] == {2, 2}, Nhfunction[x, y] == {2, 3},Nhfunction[x, y] == {3, 3}, Nhfunction[x, y] == {3, 2}}, {x, 0,1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate[Myfunction[x, y] == # & /@ z], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate@Table[Myfunction[x, y] == i, {i, z}], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

> same picture

**Update:** If you use

```
Nhfunction[c1_?NumericQ, c2_?NumericQ] := ...
```

when defining the function  `Nhfunction`, then both

```
RegionPlot[ Evaluate[Nhfunction[x, y] == # & /@ znh], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

and

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate@Table[Nhfunction[x, y] == i, {i, znh}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

give

[image]

Comment: I have an issue with the actual function [screenshot](https://ibb.co/cEvj6p) any advice about what can be failing?

Comment: @Rodrigo, what is `Nhfunction`?

Comment: I edited the question with the actual function, thanks.

Comment: @Rodrigo, if you use `Nhfunction[c1_?NumericQ, c2_?NumericQ]` in defining `Nhfunction`, both `RegionPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[Nhfunction[x, y] == i, {i, znh}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
  1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` and `RegionPlot[
 Evaluate[Nhfunction[x, y] == # & /@ znh], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` give the desired result.